# PLSQL join results of a pipelined function to a table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have some SQL(see below), which works fine.

```
INSERT INTO timeoff (employee_id,    timeoff_date)
SELECT
  e.employee_id,
  c.date_val
FROM   employees e
  INNER JOIN table(
    generate_dates_pipelined(date '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10')
  ) c
    PARTITION BY ( e.employee_id )
      ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.date_val) - TRUNC(c.date_val, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   holidays h
  WHERE  c.date_val = h.holiday_date
)
ORDER BY
  e.employee_id,
  c.date_val;
```

I am attempting to create a function that will INSERT data as I want to get rid of the hardcoded dates in the SQL.

```
create table timeoff(
  seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
  employee_id NUMBER(6),
  timeoff_date DATE,
  timeoff_type VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'V',
  constraint timeoff_chk check (timeoff_date=trunc(timeoff_date, 'dd')),
  constraint timeoff_pk primary key (employee_id, timeoff_date)
);
```

The code in the function works fine in SQL (see above). When I am trying to port it to a procedure I'm getting a syntax error. I believe the problem is with joining the results from my pipelined function, which works fine to the employees table.  I'm unsure how to fix this problem.

Below is my test CASE. I'm testing in live sql so we can both have the same Oracle version. As I am a PLSQL novice, could someone please suggest how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance to all that answer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_date IS OBJECT (
  date_val DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF obj_date;

create or replace function generate_dates_pipelined(
  p_from  in date,
  p_to    in date
)
  return nt_date 
  pipelined
is
begin
  for c1 in (
    with calendar (start_date, end_date ) as (
      select trunc(p_from), trunc(p_to) from dual
      union all
      select start_date + 1, end_date
      from   calendar
      where  start_date + 1 <= end_date
    )
    select start_date as day
    from   calendar
  ) loop
    pipe row (obj_date(c1.day));
  end loop;
 
  return;
end generate_dates_pipelined;

create table holidays(
  holiday_date DATE not null,
  holiday_name VARCHAR2(20),
  constraint holidays_pk primary key (holiday_date),
  constraint is_midnight check ( holiday_date = trunc ( holiday_date ) )
);

INSERT into holidays (HOLIDAY_DATE,HOLIDAY_NAME)
WITH dts as (
  select to_date('01-AUG-2021 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'August  1st 2021' from dual union all
  select to_date('05-AUG-2021 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'August  5th 2021' from dual
)
SELECT * from dts;

Create table employees(
  employee_id NUMBER(6), 
  first_name VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name VARCHAR2(20),
  card_num VARCHAR2(10),
  work_days VARCHAR2(7)
);

ALTER TABLE employees
ADD (
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
);

INSERT INTO employees (
  EMPLOYEE_ID,
  first_name, 
  last_name,
  card_num,
  work_days
)
WITH names AS ( 
  SELECT 1, 'Jane',     'Doe',      'F123456', 'NYYYYYN'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 'Madison', 'Smith', 'R33432','NYYYYYN' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'Justin',   'Case',     'C765341','NYYYYYN' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4, 'Mike',     'Jones',      'D564311','NYYYYYN' FROM dual 
)
SELECT * FROM names;  
  
create table timeoff(
    seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
  employee_id NUMBER(6),
  timeoff_date DATE,
  timeoff_type VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'V',
  constraint timeoff_chk check (timeoff_date=trunc(timeoff_date, 'dd')),
  constraint timeoff_pk primary key (employee_id, timeoff_date)
);



--  testing 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_timeoff_requests (
  start_date DATE,
  end_date DATE
)
IS  
  type t_date is table of date;
  l_res t_date;
BEGIN
  SELECT
    e.employee_id,
    c.date_val
  FROM   employees e
    INNER JOIN ON
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_res
      FROM TABLE (
        generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date)
      )c
      PARTITION BY ( e.employee_id )
        ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.date_val) - TRUNC(c.date_val, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   holidays h
      WHERE  c.date_val = h.holiday_date
    )
    ORDER BY
      e.employee_id,
      c.date_val
  ;

-- debug 
  for i in 1..l_res.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(l_res(i));
  end loop;
END;


EXEC create_timeoff_requests (DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10');
```

Comment: You can do `not exists` just inside the date producing function without `pipe` of unnecessary rows.

Answer (score 1):

You put BULK COLLECT INTO in a very strange position. I did not check whether your statement logic is correct, but corrected the syntax error.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_timeoff_requests (start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
    IS
      type t_date is table of date;
       l_res t_date;
    BEGIN

      SELECT 
     c.date_val
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_res
     FROM   employees e
      INNER JOIN  TABLE (generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date))c
    PARTITION BY ( e.employee_id )
            ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.date_val) - TRUNC(c.date_val, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
            FROM   holidays h
            WHERE  c.date_val = h.holiday_date
           )
    ORDER BY
        e.employee_id,
         c.date_val
     ;


/**
      SELECT e.employee_id,
     c.date_val
     FROM   employees e
      INNER JOIN ON
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_res
      FROM TABLE (           generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date))c
    PARTITION BY ( e.employee_id )
            ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.date_val) - TRUNC(c.date_val, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
            FROM   holidays h
            WHERE  c.date_val = h.holiday_date
           )
    ORDER BY
        e.employee_id,
         c.date_val
     ;
**/
   -- debug
     for i in 1..l_res.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(l_res(i));
       end loop;
    END;
```

output

```
03-AUG-21
04-AUG-21
06-AUG-21
07-AUG-21
10-AUG-21
03-AUG-21
04-AUG-21
06-AUG-21
07-AUG-21
10-AUG-21
03-AUG-21
04-AUG-21
06-AUG-21
07-AUG-21
10-AUG-21
03-AUG-21
04-AUG-21
06-AUG-21
07-AUG-21
10-AUG-21
```

Comment: I want to get employee_id, date so I tried wrapping the code into a SELECT * FROM(Your code)... I got an error expecting INTO. Do I need another Type?

Comment: Can there be two INTO statements in my example or do I need to rewrite my code to be able to get the employee_id date to do the INSERT. Thanks for your help and patience

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_timeoff_requests (start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
    IS
      type t_date is table of date;
      type t_str is table of varchar2(100);
       l_res t_date;
       l_str t_str;
    BEGIN

      SELECT e.employee_id,
     c.date_val
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_str,l_res
     FROM   employees e`